# XCode: Go from compiled app to corporate license or install-CD

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, distribution

This is my first release on Mac. While we will sell the app on App Store to users and small schools, but on larger schools they don't want to give the students money and ask each one to buy and install the app on App Store. (Have we misunderstood that?)

I'm guessing that it's possible on Mac as it is on Windows etc. to have a network admin system install apps and updates over the network. How does this work, and how do we create a deliverable once the app is finished and working in XCode? Just burn the Archive onto a bootable CD and give to the network admin is enough? Do I need to make compile settings to make the Archive stand-alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Bundle any custom frameworks and make sure the Installation Directory for them is a path relative to the executable in the bundle (see [Framework Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/CreatingFrameworks.html))
2. Archive, Show in Finder, show package contents and navigate to the .app file
3. Copy it to a CD.

(I'm about to try this, but it should be correct. So if you're hovering on the down arrow, comment first instead. :))